# Using a method from an abstract class with different parameters

Tags: java, android, oop

I feel like I should know what to do but I kinda struggle with that.

I want to make a connect 4 game on android.

For that, I have a generic "multiplayer game" library with some abstract classes that I have to implement for the Connect 4.

So, I implement the "Board" (tablero) class as "TableroC4" class, and the class "Movement" as "MovementC4"; but my problem is that "Tablero" has a function, called "mueve" (move) that takes a "Movement" object for parameter, which blocks me because I can't pass my "MovementC4" nor leave it blank (otherwise I'm not implementing the abstract class).

Here are parts from my classes, to maybe make it clearer:

```
public abstract class Tablero {  
    protected abstract void mueve(Movimiento m) throws ExcepcionJuego;
    [...]
}

abstract public class Movimiento {  
    [....]
}

public class MovimientoC4 extends Movimiento {
    [....]
}

public class TableroC4 extends Tablero {
     public void mueve(Movimiento m){  //here, i want to pass a MovimientoC4 object
     //If i do pass a MovimientoC4 object, i get an error saying that my class doesn't implement "mueve" and should be abstract
         [....]
     }
}
```

What should I do?

EDIT :

I tried naively to just put "MovimientoC4" as parameter, like this (in the mueve method from TableroC4) :

```
public class TableroC4 extends Tablero {

    public void mueve(MovimientoC4 m) throws ExcepcionJuego{

    }
```

Which gives me the following : 
    "error: TableroC4 is not abstract and does not override abstract method mueve(Movimiento) in Tablero"

I tried the following :

```
public class TableroC4 extends Tablero {

public void mueve(Movimiento m) throws ExcepcionJuego{

}

public void mueve(MovimientoC4 m) throws ExcepcionJuego{

}
```

Which works, suprisingly, but i'm not happy with this solution.

Comment: You should code in English. Anyway, why can't you pass a `Movimiento` to your `mueve` method in TableroC4? And if you can't, why do you need this method at all? Are you basing your implementation on a legacy (or mandatory) interface that you can't change?

Comment: I know, but i'm forced to use spanish here. If i pass a "MovimientoC4" i get an error saying that my class must be declared abstract, unless i implement "mueve".

Comment: "i get an error saying that my class must be declared abstract". Which class? Can you please add an example, together with the error?

Comment: sure, lemme a sec

Comment: The abstract method is `protected abstract void mueve(Movimiento m)` which means you have to pass a `Movimiento` - simple as that. If you want to pass in other types you will have to modify the abstract method to use some generics or something of that nature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pass a different parameter in your child class. What you can do is keep that signature and add a  cast check at the beginning of your implementation

Comment: So there's absolutely no way to do so ? Because it's not good to have two methods with the same name just because of the library i'm using

Comment: I don't think you should have a reason to do so. My vision is that if you want to call mueve on your child object, it will always be with a MovimientoC4. So it's not a problem for you to keep the parent's signature and then add a check. That way, if you do call with MovimientoC4, it will be ok but if you call with another child of Movimiento (like maybe MovimientoC3) you'll throw an exception.